# Why mongodb .deny() isn't working (Meteor)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, database

The code like this

```
Cashier.deny({
  insert() { return true; },
  update() { return true; },
  remove() { return true; },
});
```

do nothing. I can update data from client via mongol. I have tried to write it on server side and in my js file where I made data variables /lib/collections/data.js/ both don't work. Where I have to put it or i miss somethiing

Answer (score 1):

Actually *Cashier.deny()* takes effect, of course if you has deleted "insecure" module. Try to change your collection in browser console:

```
Cashier.update({ $set: {changed: true}}, {});
```

You will get 403 error. But you can change you database using Mongol, because it's changes objects in [method on server side](https://github.com/msavin/Mongol/blob/master/server/methods.js#L2).

On deploying to production module will be deleted automatically from app.

Comment: Great. I got deleted insecure module dince i started project. Didn't know about mongol that.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove package 'insecure'. It is added by default.